# Is there a good way to use an AMP Mustache template inside a Vue <template> element?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In AMP (ampproject.org) you use the  `<template>` element to specify a Mustache template to substitute in details like the user name. It is also used in  `<amp-list>`. The problem is I cannot work out how to gracefully stop the expansion of {{ }} before the AMP template can get a chance to process it. For example, I want to do the following.

```
 <div class="site-title-bar__hello" amp-access="access" amp-access-hide>
    <template amp-access-template type="amp-mustache">
       <span>Hi {{ name }}</span>
    </template>
</div>
```

The problem is Vue expands the  `{{name}}` reference before AMP gets access to it. I tried using  `\{{` which in some engines disables the interpretation of the braces.

The solution I am currently using is the following:

```
 <div class="site-title-bar__hello" amp-access="access" amp-access-hide
   v-html=' `<template amp-access-template type="amp-mustache"><span>Hi {{ name }}</span></template>` '>
 </div>
```

That is, use v-html with a string expression in an attribute so the `{{ }}` does not get processed.

My question is whether there is a better approach?

Comment: change delimiters?